# Issue involving small mobile screen and click event jumping to the top of page

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-zorro-antd

I have tested this on my iPhone 8+ and the issue is not present.  Also it does not happen on any computer I've tested it on.

But when I use an iPhone 6 iOS 12.4 in either chrome or safari, when I click on a button or div with an angular (click) it jumps to the very top.  I cannot replicate this using developer tools in the browser.

No I am not using a tags.  All of the examples I have seen regard the # in the a tag.

The html for one of the elements looks like this:

```
<i
     nz-icon
     nzType="heart"
     [nzTheme]="
     postService.userLikesPost.value ? 'fill' : 'outline' "
     (click)="likeOrUnlikePost()"
      ></i>
```

I have a feeling it has to do with the screen size, but everything manages to fit fine on the page.  There is no side scrolling or anything and all the button does is send something to the api.  Another (click) I have on a toggle down but that also sends the user to the top.  Another is on a div that expands and again sends the user to the top.

Any idea what could be causing this?  Again there are no issues on an iphone 8+ just a smaller 6.  I did manage to open up the xcode simulators, but it only goes down to iphone8 and there were no issues with that.

I Also happen to be using ngx-infinite-scroll but I don't believe that is causing the issue because it would happen on both devices.

Edit: Found out the phone was an iphone 6 on ios 12.  It works fine on an XR and an iphone 8, 8+, and Nexus

Edit 2: I have set up my xcode simulators to use ios12.4 and that seems to be the issue.  As it works on the ios 13 iphone 7 but not the iphone 7 ios 12.4...  Could it be an angular 8 and ios 12.4 issue?  I am going to try ignoring the events default behavior and see if that works.

Edit 3: I have narrowed the problem down.  The scroll container was inside a router outlet. So the outer html looks like this.

```
<div class="main-container">
  <app-ui-navigation-header class="top-banner"></app-ui-navigation- 
  header>
   <div class="navigation-container" #navigationContainer>
     <div class="router">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     </div>
     <div class="bottom-container">
        <app-ui-bottom-banner></app-ui-bottom-banner>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the css I had

```
.main-container {
  background-color: $off-white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: .15fr 1fr;
  height: 100%;
 }

.navigation-container {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

But then I move the overflow-y: auto and the overflow scrolling to the main container like this:

```
.main-container {
  background-color: $off-white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: .15fr 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

And It works just fine.  I would like to keep the header and have the .navigation-container be the one to scroll.  But I am making progress.

Comment: If you tack on a `preventDefault()` does it persist? Eg; `(click)="likeOrUnlikePost();event.preventDefault()"`

Comment: I actually passed $event into the method and tried .preventDefault() and .stopPropagation() but neither worked.  I didn't know you could do it this way though, thats pretty neat.  Unfortunately I'm still having the issue though.

Comment: @ChrisW. I temporarily fixed if you look at my edit 3.  Any idea if this has to do with the router outlet?

Comment: Oh sorry man I didn't notice your `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` which is an ios explicit prefix that interacts with that built in that if I remember correctly automatically tacks on an event listener for `touchmove` for chrome and safari something similar which when in a child element could cause what you're seeing. By chance at the document level do you specify like `html { height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: auto }` ? Either way pretty positive it's not an angular thing.

Comment: @ChrisW. well I added the webkit-overflow-scrolling hoping it would fix the issue.  But I removed that and tried the .preventDefault() and it still had the original problem where it scrolls to the top of the container.  At the document level I have.   html, body { height: 100%; }

Comment: @ChrisW. If I comment out the html, body { height: 100%} it does actually show the header a lot better on mobile though.  Still has the jump issue but it had been squeezing the header to the top kind of halfway hidden when you scrolled down.

Comment: Ya if I could see a way to reproduce it these things are usually pretty easy to nail down but at the moment I'm just taking shots in the dark amigo. :D

Comment: @ChrisW. Hey I appreciate it anyway.  If I can set this up in a plunker of something I will let you know.  Granted you would need a device with ios 12.4 to test it.  Thats the only part that really confuses me.  Either way, thanks a lot for pushing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue clicking on a button in an iFrame on iOS 12.4 and found a solution that worked for me. Every time I clicked on my input button, the screen would jump scroll up. Once I put in a height, overflow and scrolling for the html and body tags, it was fixed. It happens to all iOS 12.4 iPhones iOS when running through my xCode simulator.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  overflow-y:auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```